# mysql not completing execution when using nested query with greater/lesser than condition and limit on huge tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been playing around for days with this query,

```
select slno,Power_Factor_L32_Avg 
from power_logger pl 
where (pl.slno between 1851219 and 2042099) 
  and meter_id="logger1" 
  and pl.Power_Factor_L32_Avg is not null
  and case when (((pl.slno=1851219) 
                and ((pl.Power_Factor_L32_Avg) not between 0.400 and 1.000)) 
             or ((pl.slno=2042099) and 
                 ((pl.Power_Factor_L32_Avg) not between 0.400 and 1.000)) 
             or ((pl.Power_Factor_L32_Avg not between 0.400 and 1.000) and 
               (((select p2.Power_Factor_L32_Avg 
                  from power_logger p2 
                  where p2.slno=(select slno 
                                 from power_logger 
                                 where slno>pl.slno 
                                   and Power_Factor_L32_Avg is not null 
                                 order by slno asc limit 1)) 
                 between 0.400 and 1.000) 
             or ((select p4.Power_Factor_L32_Avg 
                  from power_logger p4 
                  where p4.slno=(select slno  
                                 from power_logger 
                                 where slno<pl.slno 
                                   and Power_Factor_L32_Avg is not null 
                                 order by slno desc limit 1 )) 
                between 0.400 and 1.000)))) 
           then (case when (((pl.slno=1851219) 
                        and ((select p10.Power_Factor_L32_Avg 
                              from power_logger p10 
                              where p10.slno=pl.slno+1) is null 
                          or (select p10.Power_Factor_L32_Avg 
                              from power_logger p10 
                              where p10.slno=pl.slno+1) between 0.400 and 1.000)) 
                        or (((select p5.Power_Factor_L32_Avg
                              from power_logger p5 
                              where p5.slno=(select slno
                                             from power_logger  
                                              where slno<pl.slno 
                                                and Power_Factor_L32_Avg is not null 
                                              order by slno desc limit 1 )) 
                              between 0.400 and 1.000) 
                          and ((select p6.Power_Factor_L32_Avg 
                                from power_logger p6 
                                where p6.slno=(select slno 
                                               from power_logger 
                                               where slno>pl.slno 
                                                 and Power_Factor_L32_Avg is not null 
                                               order by slno asc limit 1 )) 
                              between 0.400 and 1.000))) 
                      then 0=1 
                      else 1 
                      end) 
             else 0=1 
           end 
order by slno asc
```

It would be hard to understand the query at a glance but it is querying a table having millions of records. The only issue here is the nested queries "`select slno from power_logger where
slno<pl.slno and Power_Factor_L32_Avg is not null order by slno desc limit 1`" and "`select slno from power_logger where
slno>pl.slno and Power_Factor_L32_Avg is not null order by slno desc limit 1`" which is used to find serial no.(slno) of the previous and next records of the current record respectively having non null values. When these queries are run by itself it gives the serial number in just a few microseconds but when included in the query above, it messes up the whole thing and the process needs to be explicitly killed. 
The query above executes in less than 1.5 sec if the nested queries are not used and instead it is replaced by the next/previous serial number irrespective of whether it is null or not.

This is not going anywhere. Appreciate if any one could help me out.

New query by using temporary table,

```
create temporary table temp(
  id int auto_increment
  ,slno int
  ,pf decimal(10,4)
  ,primary key(id)
);

insert into temp(slno,pf)
(select slno,Power_Factor_L32_Avg 
 from power_logger 
 where slno between 1851219 and 2042099 
 and meter_id='logger1' 
 and Power_Factor_L32_Avg is not null);

select pl.slno,pl.Power_Factor_L32_Avg,t1.slno,t1.pf 
from power_logger pl 
left join temp t1 on t1.slno>pl.slno 
where pl.slno between 1851219 and 2042099 and pl.meter_id='logger1' 
and pl.Power_Factor_L32_Avg is not null;
```

This is to test if the next `slno` where power factor is null is fetched together with the `slno` from power_logger table. This does not work either. I am not sure if there is any other work around to get the next `slno` without using the greater than sign.

Comment: Try changing these to `SELECT TOP 1` rather than having `LIMIT 1` at the end. It may be that MySQL can optimise those subqueries better, and then you won't see such a big slowdown.

Comment: @Hbcdev: Thanks for your quick response. I am getting syntax error using TOP 1. I haven't used it before and I guess it is only applicable in transact sql.

Comment: That's not a query. It is a spreadsheet-macro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By doing some modification to Hbcdev's answers,

`select c.slno,c.Power_Factor_L32_Avg from 
(select p.slno as cur,a.slno as next,@s1 as prev,(@s1:=p.slno) from 
(select @s1:=0) d,power_logger p join (SELECT a.slno, @s AS prev, ( @s := a.slno ) ne from 
power_logger a,(SELECT @s:=0) c where a.slno between 1851219 and 2042099 
and a.Power_Factor_L32_Avg is not null and a.meter_id='logger1') as a on a.prev=p.slno 
where p.slno between 1851219 and 2042099 and p.Power_Factor_L32_Avg is not null and 
p.meter_id='logger1')d ,power_logger c where c.slno=d.cur and (((c.slno=1851219 or c.slno=2042099) and (c.Power_Factor_L32_Avg not between 0.400 and 1.000)) 
 or ((c.Power_Factor_L32_Avg 
not between 0.400 and 1.000) and (((select p2.Power_Factor_L32_Avg from power_logger p2 
where p2.slno=d.next) between 0.4 and 1.000) or ((select p3.Power_Factor_L32_Avg 
from power_logger p3 where p3.slno=d.prev) between 0.4 and 1.000)))) 
and not (((c.slno=1851219) and ((select p10.Power_Factor_L32_Avg from power_logger p10 
where p10.slno=c.slno+1) is null or (select p10.Power_Factor_L32_Avg from power_logger p10 
where p10.slno=c.slno+1) between 0.400 and 1.000)) or (((select p5.Power_Factor_L32_Avg 
from power_logger p5 where p5.slno=d.prev) between 0.400 and 1.000) and 
((select p6.Power_Factor_L32_Avg from power_logger p6 where p6.slno=d.next) 
between 0.400 and 1.000))) order by slno asc`

This gets executed in around 6 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is that you're doing far too much work with case statements. You're also repeating a lot of work.

First of all, pre-compute the result of this for every row in p1, and store it in a temporary table:

```
select slno  
from power_logger 
where slno<pl.slno 
  and Power_Factor_L32_Avg is not null 
order by slno desc limit 1
```

Do this with

```
create temporary table temp(
  slno int
  ,other_slno int
);

INSERT INTO temp(slno, other_slno)(
SELECT main.slno, second.slno
FROM power_logger main 
JOIN (SELECT other.slno FROM power_logger AS other
      where other.slno< main.slno 
      and Power_Factor_L32_Avg is not null 
      order by other.slno desc limit 1) second

);
```

Then in your main query, do
    SELECT _
    FROM power_logger
    LEFT JOIN temp ON power_logger.slno = temp.slno
    LEFT JOIN power_logger other ON temp.other_slno = other.slno

This means that everywhere you currently use something like

```
 (select p4.Power_Factor_L32_Avg 
              from power_logger p4 
              where p4.slno=(select slno  
                             from power_logger 
                             where slno<pl.slno 
                               and Power_Factor_L32_Avg is not null 
                             order by slno desc limit 1 )
```

you can instead get this value as `òther.Power_Factor_L32_Avg`.

That will make it much faster to access every time you use it. Info on temporary tables is very easily found on Google, eg. http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-temporary-table/

Secondly, only use CASE statements for much simpler conditions. Your current query has boolean logic inside some of the WHEN statements that is replicated in the corresponding THEN statements. It's also a bad sign that the result of the CASE is true or false.

Instead, put the boolean logic in the WHERE. I've copied and pasted the below from your original query, so it should be about right.

```
WHERE <Other clauses> ....
  AND (
    ((pl.slno=1851219) 
            and ((pl.Power_Factor_L32_Avg) not between 0.400 and 1.000)) 
         or ((pl.slno=2042099) and 
             ((pl.Power_Factor_L32_Avg) not between 0.400 and 1.000)) 
         or ((pl.Power_Factor_L32_Avg not between 0.400 and 1.000) and 
           (((select p2.Power_Factor_L32_Avg 
              from power_logger p2 
              where p2.slno=(select slno 
                             from power_logger 
                             where slno>pl.slno 
                               and Power_Factor_L32_Avg is not null 
                             order by slno asc limit 1)) 
             between 0.400 and 1.000) 
         or ((select p4.Power_Factor_L32_Avg 
              from power_logger p4 
              where p4.slno=(select slno  
                             from power_logger 
                             where slno<pl.slno 
                               and Power_Factor_L32_Avg is not null 
                             order by slno desc limit 1 )) 
            between 0.400 and 1.000)))

    AND NOT 
        ((pl.slno=1851219) 
            and ((select p10.Power_Factor_L32_Avg 
                  from power_logger p10 
                  where p10.slno=pl.slno+1) is null 
              or (select p10.Power_Factor_L32_Avg 
                  from power_logger p10 
                  where p10.slno=pl.slno+1) between 0.400 and 1.000)) 
              or (((select p5.Power_Factor_L32_Avg
                 from power_logger p5 
                  where p5.slno=(select slno
                                 from power_logger  
                                  where slno<pl.slno 
                                    and Power_Factor_L32_Avg is not null 
                                  order by slno desc limit 1 )) 
                  between 0.400 and 1.000) 
              and ((select p6.Power_Factor_L32_Avg 
                    from power_logger p6 
                    where p6.slno=(select slno 
                                   from power_logger 
                                   where slno>pl.slno 
                                     and Power_Factor_L32_Avg is not null 
                                   order by slno asc limit 1 )) 
                  between 0.400 and 1.000))
  )
```

This should help bring the times down (particularly using the temp table). If it doesn't, post the new version back on SO, and we can try to replace some of the subqueries with 'JOIN's (which will be more efficient again).

Comment: Thanks a lot for you response. Unfortunately, by changing the case statements to boolean logic it only returns two rows and takes more execution time. Also, if we use temporary table, we still have to use select statement to select the slno from temporary table which I think is as good as what the current query does.

Comment: Using the nested select statement is messing up the whole thing. It executes perfectly with all the case statements and by substituting the nested select queries by slno=pl.slno+1 / slno=pl.slno-1. I really have to use nested select because I need the next slno where power_factor_L32_Avg is not null and power_factor_L32_Avg at pl.slno+1 or pl.slno-1 may be null.

Comment: Use the temporary table. It'll be much faster than what you already have. The temp table will stay in memory, will stop the query repeating work, and will involve a much simpler query to lookup the right row. Try it!

Comment: I tried using temporary table but the issue is it cannot be referenced more than once in a single select statement and it gives the error "cannot reopen temporary table".

Comment: Incorporate it with a join. Join the temporary table with the real table, then join the original table again on the *other* column of the temporary table. Then you'll have access to the original table and to the "previous" slno's row everywhere in the query. It will be much, much, much faster.

Comment: I created temporary table with slnos and power_factor_L32_Avg where Power_Factor_L32_Avg is not null and then joined it with main power_logger table on condition that the slno on temp table is greater than slno of power_logger table so that we get the current slno as well as next slno where Power_Factor_L32_Avg is not null on the same row. It still reiterates the same issue.

Comment: Please edit the question with the new query so I can see it. Ta.

Comment: I have added the new query to the question. It is to just test if temporary table serves our purpose by using join. Could you please see if I am doing anything wrong with the join condition.

Comment: This isn't the temporary table I meant. See my updated answer. I haven't tested that code so it might need a little adjusting. If you can't get it to work, then I suggest a SQL Fiddle at http://sqlfiddle.com/ with the right schema and some sample data, then post the link to that back here. It'll make it much easier for me to help you!

Comment: The sub-query after join in the insert query used to insert data to temp table is correlated to main query which doesn't work. It gives error saying "unknown column main.slno in where clause".

Comment: I even tried using session variable to insert into temp table that didnot either work. `select @s1 as id1,p.slno from power_logger p ,(select @s1:=0) as s1 where slno between 1851219 and 2042099 and @s1:=(select p1.slno from power_logger p1 where p1.slno>p.slno and p1.Power_Factor_L32_Avg is not null order by p1.slno asc limit 1)`.This would work if p.slno is substituted by a random number with in limit mentioned in query's where clause but when the slno from main query is used, it messes up the execution. It is again the nested select causing the problem and I guess it scans the whole table.

Comment: Please can you make a SQL Fiddle for this? It will make it much easier to help you.

Comment: I tried in sql fiddle by creating table with just around 10 rows and it was working fine. The original table has millions of rows and that is where the problem occurs. I am not sure if you can recreate that in fiddle.

Comment: It's enough to test the temporary table. It won't recreate the speed problem but will let me test a whole load of different queries for you to try (without creating syntax errors).

Comment: I have created the schema and the link is http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/64829c
You can run the same query for creating temporary table which gives you the error of missing column.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9ad78 fixes that. You'll need to add the word "temporary" back in (have to remove it here to use the temp table on the left hand side). http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a3640f/12 uses the resulting table to find the 'other' row for each 'original' row, as I suggested you do. Now over to you to refactor your original WHERE clause!

Comment: That isn't giving a result with the original table. The insert query to the temp table has the same sub-query `SELECT other.slno FROM power_logger AS other
      where other.slno< main.slno 
      and Power_Factor_L32_Avg is not null 
      order by other.slno desc limit 1` which created the issue in the original query mentioned in the question. I still think even if you limit to one result it performs a complete table scan to find a value lesser than main.slno and when this is repeated for every main.slno selected(190880 times for range between 1851219 and 2042099) stuffs up execution time.

Comment: Have you tried it with your original query? Please do so and post the fiddle. It is hard to second-guess query SQL query optimizations. It is still doing the search (it won't be table-wide; SQL is cleverer than that) but it is only doing it once, meaning your far more complicated query can avoid subqueries altogether. It will be faster overall, but that doesn't mean it'll be instantaneous to execute.

Comment: I thought of a way to generate the temp table without a subquery: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2ab7d/1 This may well be faster again.

Comment: Here is the link to fiddle with my original query http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c26a2/1
It gives result quickly and is perfect.I am clueless on why it stuffs up when you run it on a large table but when the greater than condition causing the problem is replaced by equal to, it still gives result in fraction of seconds.

Comment: I am sorry to say that the new query to insert into temporary table did not work with the original table because the join condition satisfying 'other.slno< main.slno' will create a massive amount of rows for example row having slno 2042099 alone matches with 190880 rows which have slno lesser than that. It works well if the range of slno is short for example 1851219 and 1851225

Comment: I think that's very unlikely to be the reason why. MySQL is clever enough to spot that it needs the MAX order number and optimise for that. Do you have an execution plan to support that claim? Is it slower than before? Improved versions of the main select at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dfbe1/1 and http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dfbe1/3

Comment: In the query execution plan obtained by adding Explain keyword to the main query I get a table with Ref value as null for all the four dependent subqueries that causes the problem and Ref value is 'func' for all other dependent subqueries.

Comment: And is it slower? Can you limit it to 1000 or so rows and demonstrate which is faster? Did you try the SQL from the latest fiddle I put up?

Comment: Did you mean limiting the whole query to 1000 rows? If so it isn't working.

Comment: Isn't working how? It goes but is very slow? There's a syntax error? You have to give more info than that if you want help! How many rows do you have to limit it to before it starts to work? Can you upload a complete project to SQL Fiddle? Also, while I think about it, have you got an index defined on your main table, on `slno`? I can't just fix this stuff for you without any data, and just saying "it isn't working" doesn't help much.

Comment: Sorry for not giving you much information and that is just because I am a newbie and I appreciate the effort you are putting to solve it. 
As far as the indexes are concerned the field date and time are indexed together. meter_id is also indexed. These indexes have been created to make the data insertion efficient. The table has all together 310 columns and 1919930 rows. These are the readings from electric power logger. slno is the primary key and auto increment field. As it is that huge, I don't think it could be uploaded to sql fiddle. Please let me know if you want more details.

Comment: `slno` will have an index on it too because it's the primary key, so that's good. Can you do some experiments with the temporary table, to see how the time it takes to create varies with the size of the table?

Comment: I shall give you select access to the power_logger table in mysql server if you would like to have a look at it. But I don't want to put the url and credentials on a public blog. Can you think of any alternative?

Comment: I haven't really got time to the work on this myself -- just pointing you in the right direction...

Comment: Got a way to fetch the current and next slno
`select p.slno as cur,a.slno as next from power_logger p join (SELECT  a.slno, @s  AS prev, ( @s := a.slno ) ne
FROM power_logger a,(SELECT @s:=0) c where a.slno between 1851219 and 2042099 and a.Power_Factor_L32_Avg is not null and a.meter_id='logger1') as a on  a.prev=p.slno where  
p.slno between 1851219 and 2042099 and p.Power_Factor_L32_Avg is not null and p.meter_id='logger1'`. Doing one more join to fetch previous slno would solve everything but again execution time slows down. But this query to fetch current and next slno  executes in 1.5sec

Comment: Finally I found something which gets executed at least in 6 seconds. Thanks for helping me through out and it worked just by joining tables and using some session variables.